# Translate Expression Tree for nested model

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have expression tree converter which convert an expression from a type to another type and also I have nested model like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }

    public IList<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

and I have Dto for this class:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }

    public IList<TicketDto> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

and here is code for my converter:

```
public static class ExpressionConverter<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, TType>> Convert<TDto, TType>(Expression<Func<TDto, TType>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            return (null);
        }

        var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "ent");

        var converter = new ConversionVisitor(newParameter);

        var bodyExpression = converter.Visit(expression.Body);
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TType>>(bodyExpression, newParameter);

        return (lambdaExpression);
    }

    #region ConversionVisitor Nested Class

    private sealed class ConversionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _newParameter;

        public ConversionVisitor(ParameterExpression newParameter)
        {
            _newParameter = newParameter;
        }

        #region Overrides

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return (_newParameter);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            var newExpression = Visit(node.Expression);
            var newMemberInfo = newExpression.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name).First();
            var newMemberExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(newExpression, newMemberInfo);

            return (newMemberExpression);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            MemberExpression memberExpression;
            Expression leftExpression;

            var binaryExpression = node.Right as BinaryExpression;
            if (binaryExpression != null)
            {
                leftExpression = binaryExpression.Left;
            }
            else
            {
                var constantExpression = node.Right as ConstantExpression;
                if (constantExpression != null)
                {
                    leftExpression = node.Left;
                }
                else
                {
                    var unaryExpression = node.Right as UnaryExpression;
                    if (unaryExpression != null)
                    {
                        leftExpression = unaryExpression.Operand;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (base.VisitBinary(node));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (leftExpression is MethodCallExpression)
            {
                return (base.VisitBinary(node));
            }
            if (leftExpression is BinaryExpression)
            {
                return (base.VisitBinary(node));
            }

            var leftUnaryExpression = leftExpression as UnaryExpression;
            if (leftUnaryExpression != null)
            {
                memberExpression = (MemberExpression)leftUnaryExpression.Operand;
            }
            else
            {
                var leftMemberExpression = leftExpression as MemberExpression;
                if (leftMemberExpression != null)
                {
                    memberExpression = leftMemberExpression;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Ouch Disable Shodim");
                }
            }

            var memberInfo = memberExpression.Member;
            if (memberInfo == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("memberInfo");
            }
            return (base.VisitBinary(node));
        }

        #endregion Overrides
    }

    #endregion ConversionVisitor Nested Class
}
```

When I have an expression like this

```
Expression<Func<PersonModel, bool>> expr = p => p.Age == 29 && p.Tickets.Any(t => t.Id == 1);
```

My converter cannot translate right part of expression for `Ticket` because converter is not aware of type of Ticket. Is there a way fixing this problem ? I'm looking for solution which converter can dig down N level into model.

Comment: Can you include the exact error you are getting and where it is happening?

Comment: **Sequence contains no elements** while converter visit t.Id

Comment: 1. What is that `VisitBinary()` supposed to do? The returned value is always the same. 2. In your example expression, you need to translate old `p` to new `p`. But your `VisitParameter()` also translates old `t` to **new `p`**.

Comment: Ya you right, problem is `t` will be translated to new `p` instead of new `t`.